# Series with sine and cosine to be expressed as a polynomial

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

Is someone able to express:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} 
      \displaystyle\left( \frac{\alpha\sin(\alpha\pi k)}{2(\pi k)((2\alpha k)^2-1)}+
      \displaystyle\frac{(3(2\alpha k)^2-1)\cos(\alpha\pi k)}{2(\pi k)^2((2\alpha k)^2-1)^2} \right)^2, $$

for $k\neq\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\alpha}$ and $\alpha\in[0;1]$, as a simple polynomial in $\alpha$ ?

Hint: This is the 2nd order of a physical phenomenon (in signal processing theory) whose 1st order can be expressed as:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} 
      \displaystyle\frac{\cos(\alpha\pi k)^2}{4(\pi k)^2((2\alpha k)^2-1)^2}=\alpha^2 \left(\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{\pi^2}\right)-\frac{\alpha}{16}+\frac{1}{24} ,$$
and I confirm that there is a factor 3 in the right term, this is not a mistake.

Comment: What simulations?

Comment: Could you fix the unbalanced parenthese in the second term ?

Comment: $k$ is somehow still broken, given that it's used in the sum and outside with odd restriction.